# Reading in \n and EOF from the user, if user enters a string?

Tags: c++

I want to check if the user enters \n and EOF in the string that they enter. So far, I've tried

```
getline(cin, temp);
if(cin.EOF())//tried and did not work
  cout << "failed EOF";
if(temp[temp.size()] == '\n')
  cout << "\n";
```

Comment: Don't use `eof()`, use the boolean conversion instead: `if( !cin ) throw "some read operation failed";`

Comment: there is no `cin.EOF()`

Comment: What is your reasoning for using these two conditions?

Comment: why not just use `if(getline(cin,temp))`?

Comment: Please reply to us by posting your response as a comment.

Comment: Basically what the user is supposed to do is enter a string of length 10 and then press EOF key. If the amount of characters is less than that amount, I'm supposed to print that the amount of characters is incorrect and then enter what the user inputted last, this could be a value , \n or EOF.

Comment: @AzureWorld Does my answer not help with the problem you've given in the question?

Comment: Could you explain what you did, i've never used cin.expections nor eofbase and fail base. Thanks. Also, could i use get to read in the line, and since the \n will still be in the buffer, just read that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Determining a valid extraction is more straightforward than you might think. If the extraction fails, it will be reflected in the program through the stream state of the input stream used for the extraction. Moreoever, `std::getline()` returns the stream, which (when implicitly converted to boolean), will check its stream state for the appropriate bits. You can take advantage of this functionality and encase the extraction in an `if` statement, which will implicitly convert its parameter to boolean:

> ```
> if (std::getline(std::cin, temp))
> ```

If the extraction performed successfully, the `if` statement will execute. If you want to response to the user through the stream state, you can set the exceptions mask in stream and check for any thrown exceptions:

> ```
> if (std::getline(std::cin, temp))
> {
>     std::cout << "Extraction produced: " << temp << std::endl;
> }
>
> try {
>     std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::eofbit);
> } 
> catch (std::ios_base::failure&)
> {
>     std::ios_base::iostate exceptions = std::cin.exceptions();
>
>     if ((exceptions & std::ios_base::eofbit) && std::cin.eof())
>     {
>         std::cout << "You've reached the end of the stream.";
>     }
> }
> ```

<sub>The above is just an example. I haven't tried to compile it. :)</sub>